# How can I declare an object's member field as volatile?

Tags: java, volatile

If I have a variable of type SomeClass and one of its public members, say `public int counter` will be accessed by multiple threads, how can I declare volatility on that member field if I'm unable to modify SomeClass?  Ideally, I'm guessing that `counter` would be declared `volatile`, but I'm unable to do that.

Comment: You can't.  Would it be adequate to, instead, externally synchronize your access to that field?

Comment: Does protecting access to a field by use of locks imply that the reading thread won't use a cached value?

Comment: @Philip no, using a lock does not guarantee the memory barrier you're looking for.

Comment: lock guarantees memory barrier

Comment: By declaring it as volatile. There's only one way. If you can't modify the class you can't modify it's member declarations either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is incompatible with separate compiling, and is therefore not possible. The volatile qualifier directs the compiler to treat a variable differently on each access, so every access to that variable from the module to the source of which you have no access would need to change as well. Since that module is compiled already, changing the way it treats some of its variables is not possible.